# Is there a way to know my caller's program name?

Tags: c#, html

I have a C# program which is launching a HTML in this way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("MarketBatchLoad.html");
```

Can my html file know which program is launching it? For example, my C# program's name is ABC.exe, so I need to capture 'ABC.exe' in my html file. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get file name and extension and pass in HTML :

[`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.friendlyname.aspx) will output `test.exe`